# How to restart current_level for every third missed_day (3 strikes you're out!)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, checkbox, integer

[image]

For example if a user is on Level 4: **Day 50**, he is pushed back to **Day 45**.

```
  case n_days     
      when 0..9     # Would go back to 0
        1
      when 10..24   # Back to 10
        2
      when 25..44   # Back to 25
        3
      when 45..69   # Back to 45
        4
      when 70..99   # Back to 70
        5
      else
        "Mastery"
    end
```

Then let's say he makes his way back up again, this time to **Day 68**, if he again checks off 3 `missed_days` he will again be pushed back to **Day 45**:

[image]

The **_form** (represented by the above pictures):

```
<label id="<%= @habit.id %>" class="habit-id"> Missed: </label>
  <% @habit.levels.each_with_index do |level, index| %>
    <p>
      <label id="<%= level.id %>" class="level-id"> Level <%= index + 1 %>: </label>
      <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 0, {class: "habit-check"} %>
      <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 1, {class: "habit-check"} %>
      <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 2, {class: "habit-check"} %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
```

**habit.rb**

```
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable
    has_many :levels
    serialize :committed, Array
    validates :date_started, presence: true
    before_save :current_level
    acts_as_taggable
    scope :private_submit, -> { where(private_submit: true) }
    scope :public_submit, -> { where(private_submit: false) }

attr_accessor :missed_one, :missed_two, :missed_three

    def save_with_current_level
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.save
    end

    def self.committed_for_today
      today_name = Date::DAYNAMES[Date.today.wday].downcase
      ids = all.select { |h| h.committed.include? today_name }.map(&:id)
      where(id: ids)
    end 

    def current_level_strike
      levels[current_level - 1] # remember arrays indexes start at 0
    end

    def current_level
          return 0 unless date_started
          def committed_wdays
            committed.map do |day|    
              Date::DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize)
            end
          end

          def n_days
            ((date_started.to_date)..Date.today).count do |date| 
              committed_wdays.include? date.wday
            end - self.missed_days
          end     

      case n_days     
          when 0..9
            1
          when 10..24
            2
          when 25..44
            3
          when 45..69
            4
          when 70..99
            5
          else
            6
        end
    end
end
```

**habit.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var handleChange = function() {
    habit = $(this).parent().prev().attr("id");
    level = $('label', $(this).parent()).attr("id");
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/habits/" + habit + "/levels/" + level + "/days_missed",
        method: "POST"
      });
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/habits/" + habit + "/levels/" + level + "/days_missed/1",
        method: "DELETE"
      });
    }
    if (!$('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)', $(this).parent()).length) {
      /* this is just an example, you will have to ammend this */
      $(this).parent().append($('<input type="checkbox" class="habit-check">'));
      $(this).parent().append($('<input type="checkbox" class="habit-check">'));
      $(this).parent().append($('<input type="checkbox" class="habit-check">'));
      $(".habit-check").on('change',handleChange);
    }
  }
  $(".habit-check").on('change',handleChange);
});
```

**days_missed_controller.rb**

```
class DaysMissedController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def create
    habit = Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
    habit.missed_days = habit.missed_days + 1
    habit.save!
    level = habit.levels.find(params[:level_id])
    level.missed_days = level.missed_days + 1
    level.save!
    head :ok # this returns an empty response with a 200 success status code
  end

  def destroy
    habit = Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
    habit.missed_days = habit.missed_days - 1
    habit.save
    level = habit.levels.find(params[:level_id])
    level.missed_days = level.missed_days - 1
    level.save!
    head :ok # this returns an empty response with a 200 success status code
  end
end
```

Here's the **Gist** of it: https://gist.github.com/RallyWithGalli/c66dee6dfb9ab5d338c2

Please let me know if you need anymore code, explanations, or pictures :)

Comment: explain in concise manner what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi @ParitoshPiplewar I rewrote the question. Hopefully you find it more clear and concise :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution:

You need to keep track the days you lost at the moment you get 3 missed days (you need to add a field in level):

**migration file.rb**

```
class AddDaysLostToLevels < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :levels, :days_lost, :integer,   default: 0
  end
```

end

Then change controller days_missed to reset when you get 3 missed days and store the days you lost when you start again level (in the variable days_lost):

```
class DaysMissedController < ApplicationController

  def create
    habit = Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
    habit.missed_days = habit.missed_days + 1
    habit.save!
    level = habit.levels.find(params[:level_id])
    level.missed_days = level.missed_days + 1
    if level.missed_days == 3
      level.missed_days = 0
      level.days_lost += habit.calculate_days_lost + 1
    end
    ...remain the same
```

Now we need to define "calculate_days_lost" and "real_missed_days" methods in habit.rb.

Remember to use self.real_missed_days instead self.missed_days in current_level method: (they are diferent because you can start again a level). New habit.rb will be like this:

```
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments, as: :commentable
has_many :levels
serialize :committed, Array
validates :date_started, presence: true
before_save :current_level
acts_as_taggable
scope :private_submit, -> { where(private_submit: true) }
scope :public_submit, -> { where(private_submit: false) }

attr_accessor :missed_one, :missed_two, :missed_three

def save_with_current_level
    self.levels.build
    self.levels.build
    self.levels.build
    self.levels.build
    self.levels.build
    self.save
end

def self.committed_for_today
  today_name = Date::DAYNAMES[Date.today.wday].downcase
  ids = all.select { |h| h.committed.include? today_name }.map(&:id)
  where(id: ids)
end 

def current_level_strike
  levels[current_level - 1] # remember arrays indexes start at 0
end

  def real_missed_days
     value = 0
     levels.each do |level|
       if level.missed_days != nil 
         value += level.missed_days + level.days_lost
       end  
     end
     value
  end

  def committed_wdays
   committed.map do |day|    
    Date::DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize)
   end
  end

  def n_days
    ((date_started.to_date)..Date.today).count do |date| 
      committed_wdays.include? date.wday
    end - self.real_missed_days
  end    

  def calculate_days_lost
    case n_days   
      when 0..9
        n_days
      when 10..24
        n_days-10
      when 25..44
        n_days-25
      when 45..69
        n_days-45
      when 70..99
        n_days-70
      else
        n_days-100
    end
  end

 def current_level
   return 0 unless date_started
   case n_days    
      when 0..9
        1
      when 10..24
        2
      when 25..44
        3
      when 45..69
        4
      when 70..99
        5
      else
        6
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this thoughtful answer :) I'm having the greatest difficulty integrating it with habit.rb `current_level`. From the looks of what you put I'm not sure if you intended for it to be left out or put elsewhere. I need it though for 1) to show the user in the index what level his habit is on `habit.current_level` and 2) I recently added `<% if @habit.current_level >= (index + 1) %>` to the _form so that only checkboxes for the `current_level` and past levels are shown (not future levels).

Comment: current level method still the same, I just put the two methods to add in habit.rb (real_missed_days and calculate_days_lost). The only change is to use self.real_missed_days instead self.missed_days.

Comment: I updated question manfergo with my attempt at your code. Also n_days use to have an integer for each level `1`, `2`, `3`, etc I'm worried taking those out will create further issues.

Comment: Okay I think I know what you mean. One sec :)

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the delay I ran into a few problems that I have been working on relating to habits before I was able to see if your code worked. It looks like it works, which is absolutely amazing! Before I jump the gun and check it off I'm just waiting on getting this question answered hopefully: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314826/how-to-count-a-method-within-a-method so that is easier for me to see how it all works together :)

Comment: Hello. I have been answers some of your questions for a while in stackoverflow. Because it seems that your using this space to have assistance for your code for free instead making questions to learn I decided not to answer more of your questions. But you post this question in elance.com and offer $25 for answerd and it seems that is a fair way to have assistance. So I make a Proposal(as papayalabs) and answered but it seems you now forget to check it off.  Please clarify the situation. Regards.

Comment: Sorry I wanted to be positive it was right before checking. It is. Thank you :) I'll message you over at elance for more details.

Comment: Thank u for responding!

Comment: I edit the answer (habit.rb) and order the code to make it more legible and beatiful.

Comment: Papayalabs I created a new offer on elance. I hit my invite max otherwise I would tell you there. Would you be interested in looking into the problem? If you solve it I'll pay you $50 :] Elance: https://www.elance.com/job/74900601/proposals, SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064486/the-mystery-of-the-disappearing-checkmarks

Comment: I'll take a look Anthony. Thanks for the invitation.

Comment: My pleasure. I figure you already have a background with the code so best to turn to you :] Let me know if you have any questions. I'll be around, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81751/room-for-anthonygalli-com-and-papayalabs

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve here is expect a user to do something every day for a couple of days. If he doesn't do it 3 times in a given "level period" you want to reset his "level progress", correct?

If so, the simplest solution would be to add another variable, for example: `days_lost`.

Then, you could apply it in **habit.rb**:

```
n_days = ((date_started.to_date)..Date.today).count { |date| committed_wdays.include? date.wday } - self.missed_days - self.days_lost
```

Remember to update it every time user "misses" 3 times, which would look something like this in **days_missed_controller.rb**:

```
def create
  ...
  if missed_days == 3
    missed_days = 0
    days_lost = <days from beginning of the level>
  end
  ...
end
```

**UPDATE**:

`<days from beginning of the level>` could be counted by creating another helper variable, e.g. `pending_days` and give it a starting value of `0`. Every day, `pending_days += 1`.

Next we have to cases:

1: Player "misses" 3 days on his current level - we add days from the beginning of the level to the negative (lost) days, and start counting again

```
days_lost += pending_days
pending_days = 0
```

2: Player "misses" less than 3 days - we simply increase his level, and start counting again because he is on a new level

```
pending_days = 0
```

Comment: Consider something like `pending_days` which would be equal to 0 on the first day of a new level. You could increase it by 1 every day, and reset if a user passes a level. But when he fails, that would be added to his `days_lost` variable.

Comment: Sure, but `pending_days` would be your helper variable. So if a user didn't miss more than 3 days in his current level, he will start the next one with `pending_days=0`, but if he fails those `pending_days` would be transferred to `days_lost`, so `days_lost += pending_days` and `pending_days = 0`
Remember that you always subtract those `days_lost` to receive `n_days`

Comment: Yes of course. You need to be able to keep track of `days_lost`

Comment: Hey can you please tell me where I went wrong here: `if missed_days == 3,
    missed_days = 0,
    days_lost += pending_days, pending_days += 1,
pending_days = 0,
  end`. I think you were on the right track. I also just updated the question to better clarify.