# How to count a method within a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, model, integer

If we create a new method called `days_left_in_current_level`, what would we need to put in there so that we can count how many days are left in the  `current_level`?

**habit.rb**

```
def current_level
  return 0 unless date_started

  def committed_wdays
    committed.map do |day|
      Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize)
    end
  end

  def n_days
    ((date_started.to_date)..Date.today).count do |date| 
      committed_wdays.include? date.wday
    end - self.real_missed_days
  end     

  case n_days   # 1 - 6 represent the different levels  
    when 0..9
      1
    when 10..24
      2
    when 25..44
      3
    when 45..69
      4
    when 70..99
      5
    else
      6
  end
end
```

Please let me know if you need further explanation or code (here's the **[Gist](https://gist.github.com/RallyWithGalli/c66dee6dfb9ab5d338c2)** of it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def days_left_in_current_level

  def n_days
    ((date_started.to_date)..Date.today).count do |date| 
      committed_wdays.include? date.wday
    end - self.real_missed_days
  end     

    case n_days   
  when 0..9
    10-n_days
  when 10..24
    25-n_days
  when 25..44
    45-n_days
  when 45..69
    70-n_days
  when 70..99
    100-n_days
  else
    0 # No end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

a basic way of doing this: make current_level take a default parameter with the value of today. After that, in the days_left_in_current_level i would just increase the day until the level changes and count the iterations.

**keep in mind that this is almost pseudocode and haven't actually tried running it. there also should be more efficient ways of doing this.**

```
def current_level(current_date = Date.today)
...snip...
((date_started.to_date)..current_date ).count do |date| 
...snip...
end

def days_left_in_current_level
my_level = current_level
days_left = 0
next_level = current_level(Date.today + days_left + 1)

while next_level == my_level
days_left +=1 
next_level = current_level(Date.today + days_left + 1)
end

end
```