# The Mystery of the Disappearing Checkmarks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

If a user clicks a checkbox the below code will fire, but the checkmark will sometimes disappear, the box is therefore unchecked when it should be checked.

```
$(document).on("page:change", function() {
  $(".habit-check").change(function()
  {
    habit = $(this).parent().siblings(".habit-id").first().attr("id");
    level = $(this).siblings(".level-id").first().attr("id");
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
       $.ajax(
       {
         url: "/habits/" + habit + "/levels/" + level + "/days_missed",
         method: "POST"
       });
    }
    else
    {
       $.ajax(
       {
         url: "/habits/" + habit + "/levels/" + level + "/days_missed/1",
         method: "DELETE"
       });
    }
  });
});

# I ALSO TRIED USING LOCAL STORAGE, BUT IT HAD THE SAME PROBLEM.
# VERSION 2

$(document).on("page:change", function() {
{
  $(".habit-check").change(function()
  {
    habit = $(this).parent().siblings(".habit-id").first().attr("id");
    level = $(this).siblings(".level-id").first().attr("id");
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
          $.ajax({
            url: "/habits/" + habit + "/levels/" + level + "/days_missed",
            method: "POST"
          });
          localStorage.setItem("habit_"+habit+"_"+level, true);
        } else {
          $.ajax({
            url: "/habits/" + habit + "/levels/" + level + "/days_missed/1",
            method: "DELETE"
          });
          localStorage.setItem("habit_"+habit+"_"+level, false);
        }
  });
});
```

The **show page** calls the AJAX

```
<div class="strikes">
  <% if @habit.current_level_strike %> 
    <div class="btn" id="red"> <label id="<%= @habit.id %>" class="habit-id">Strikes:</label>
  <% else %> 
    <div class="btn" id="gold"> <label id="<%= @habit.id %>" class="habit-id-two">Strikes:</label>
  <% end %>
    <% @habit.levels.each_with_index do |level, index| %>
      <% if @habit.current_level >= (index + 1) %>
        <p>
          <% if @habit.current_level_strike %> 
            <label id="<%= level.id %>" class="level-id">Level <%= index + 1 %>:</label> 
          <% else %> 
            <label id="<%= level.id %>" class="level-id-two">Level <%= index + 1 %>:</label> 
          <% end %>
          <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 0, {class: "habit-check"} %>
          <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 1, {class: "habit-check"} %>
          <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 2, {class: "habit-check"} %>
       </p>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what the AJAX fires to, **days_missed_controller.rb**.

```
class DaysMissedController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def create
    habit = Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
    habit.missed_days = habit.missed_days + 1
    @habit.save!
    level = habit.levels.find(params[:level_id])
    level.missed_days = level.missed_days + 1
    if level.missed_days == 3
      level.missed_days = 0
      level.days_lost += habit.calculate_days_lost + 1
    end
    level.save!
    head :ok # this returns an empty response with a 200 success status code
  end

  def destroy
    habit = Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
    habit.missed_days = habit.missed_days - 1
    habit.save!
    level = habit.levels.find(params[:level_id])
    level.missed_days = level.missed_days - 1
    level.save!
    head :ok # this returns an empty response with a 200 success status code
  end
end
```

Here's the [**gist**](https://gist.github.com/RallyWithGalli/c66dee6dfb9ab5d338c2) of it. Please don't hesitate to ask for further code or clarification :]

I also ran into this problem when I removed turbolinks thinking that might be the issue, but it's not.

Comment: Is a page load triggered when you click the checkbox?

Comment: Also, try changing `page:change` to `page:load`

Comment: You could try setting unique names for the checkboxes, it might be that some browsers alter the state of checkboxes when one with equal name is being clicked.

Comment: @fylooi I tried both but neither worked right and a page load isn't triggered when checking the box, but the AJAX does fire.

Comment: And @fylooi after I run `rake db:reset` the checkmarks persist in development. I rather not reset the database for production if possible. I see the problem occured in development when I toyed around with switching back and forth `page:load` and `page:change`

Comment: Okay I reset the database in production @fylooi and it worked for a bit, but now it's not again, same with development. In both environments the checkmarks are being erratic. I don't know why it would work and then stop working. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Checkmarks clearing sounds like client side js, database persistence is server side. So is this client side or server side?

Comment: I think this is server side @fylooi since it happens in every browser even if I take off the cache and remove turbolinks.

Comment: What are the events that could change a checkbox's checked state? It seems that the only thing that should be able to do so is the click event itself (you note above, "a page load isn't triggered when checking the box"). But if the checkmark state is getting out of sync as you indicate, something else must also be changing its state. I don't see any sign that the checkmark state is being updated based on the change callback or as a result of the AJAX call. But I'd guess that this is at the root of your problem.

Comment: Just a quick question, are [those](http://screencast.com/t/5eJCvLmJ) the problematic checkboxes?

Comment: Thanks so much @klenwell. Pawel finally got this to work after diving deep into the code with me :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, tracked this nasty one down!

The problem lays in your HTML generated. It turns out, that the problematic ones end up performing AJAX calls to... invalid URLs (causing `404`'s)!

In your **show view**, you have code like:

```
<% if @habit.current_level_strike %> 
  <div class="btn" id="red"> <label id="<%= @habit.id %>" class="habit-id">Strikes:</label>
<% else %> 
  <div class="btn" id="gold"> <label id="<%= @habit.id %>" class="habit-id-two">Strikes:</label>
<% end %>

<!-- [...] -->

<% if @habit.current_level_strike %> 
  <label id="<%= level.id %>" class="level-id">Level <%= index + 1 %>:</label> 
<% else %> 
  <label id="<%= level.id %>" class="level-id-two">Level <%= index + 1 %>:</label> 
<% end %>
```

Why is it problematic? Well, in your JavaScript, you're relying on exact classes of `.habit-id` and `.level-id`:

```
habit = $(this).parent().siblings(".habit-id").first().attr("id");
level = $(this).siblings(".level-id").first().attr("id");
```

While according to HTML from **show view**, sometimes the proper classes are generated, and sometimes there are classes with appendix of `*-two` (`habit-id-two` and `level-id-two`).

If you try fixing the class names, so all are of the same form expected by your JavaScript (`.siblings(".habit-id")` and `.siblings(".level-id")`), the problem disappears.

**Better solution** (yes, it is possible to simplify it a bit ;))

What if we *pregenerate* urls, and set them in HTML like so:

```
<div class="strikes">
  <!-- [...] -->
    <% @habit.levels.each_with_index do |level, index| %>
      <% if @habit.current_level >= (index + 1) %>
        <p data-submit-url="<%= habit_level_days_missed_index_path({ habit_id: @habit.id, level_id: level.id }) %>"
           data-delete-url="<%= habit_level_days_missed_path({ habit_id: @habit.id, level_id: level.id, id: 1 }) %>">
          <!-- [...] -->
        </p>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, your JavaScript can be simplified to:

```
$(document).on("page:change", function() {
  $(".habit-check").change(function()
  {
    var submitUrl = $(this).parents("p").data("submit-url");
    var deleteUrl = $(this).parents("p").data("delete-url");

    if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
       $.ajax(
       {
         url: submitUrl,
         method: "POST"
       });
    }
    else
    {
       $.ajax(
       {
         url: deleteUrl,
         method: "DELETE"
       });
    }
  });
});
```

Please, be warned, that when generating **delete-url**, I've used hardcoded value of `id`, which is `1` (trying to reproduce your original behaviour), in:

```
data-delete-url="<%= habit_level_days_missed_path({ habit_id: @habit.id, level_id: level.id, id: 1 }) %>"
```

which corresponds to:

```
url: "/habits/" + habit + "/levels/" + level + "/days_missed/1"
```

in your code. Are you **100%** sure this is what you want?

Hope that helps! If you have any questions - I'm more than happy to help/explain!

Good luck!

Comment: With your simpler solution we get: `ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Habits#show
Showing /Users/galli01anthony/Desktop/Pecoce/app/views/habits/show.html.erb where line #30 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"days_missed", :id=>"5"} missing required keys: [:habit_id, :level_id]`

Comment: This is amazing thouh. I've been struggling with this for so long! How would I do the less simple version, with `(.siblings(".habit-id")` and `.siblings(".level-id"))`

Comment: Want to chat real quick?

Comment: I'll be able in about 30 min?

Comment: Perfect! I'll keep playing in the meantime :]

Comment: Ok, shall we for a sec?

Comment: Ok I've just updated the code where urls are generated. Hopefully this works now!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81898/discussion-between-anthonygalli-com-and-pawel-dawczak).